# Change user password with password confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, authlogic

I'm trying to update user password using password_confirmation to confirm it.

However, I can't find a way to correctly update my password, I set password with `password=` and `password_confirmation=` but when I watch `changed?` results, it always return false.

Any suggestion on how to solve this issue? Here is my code (change_password is called in a controller, params are correctly passed I've seen them with print):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic

  belongs_to :organization

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :organization_id, :note, :role

  validates :email, :uniqueness => true
  validates :role,  :inclusion => { :in => Rails.configuration.available_roles }

  def change_password!(pswd)
    password = pswd
    password_confirmation = pswd
    return changed? && save
  end

  def change_password(old_pswd, pswd, confirm_pswd)
    return false, 'Old password is incorrect' if !valid_password?(old_pswd, true)
    password = pswd
    password_confirmation = confirm_pswd
    # update_attributes([user: [password: pswd, password_confirmation: confirm_pswd]])
    print "--------- #{old_pswd} #{pswd} #{confirm_pswd} #{changed?.to_s} ------------"
    return changed? && save, 'New and confirm password are not correcty'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `self.` when setting attributes (which are actually 'setter' helper methods) - otherwise ruby thinks you are creating new local variables:

```
self.password = pswd
self.password_confirmation = pswd
```

Comment: Oh **really**?!?! It's really strange I didn't know such a thing, but thanks a lot!